# A set such that for every $i \in S$, $i^2 \in S$ as well.

Tags: complex-numbers

I was considering the largest possible set of complex numbers which contained the squares of every element; that is, the largest possible set $S$ such that for every $i \in S$, $i^2 \in S$ as well.

Would this set include every complex number? At first, I reasoned that it would only include 1, -1, 0, i, and -i, but then realized that $\sqrt{i} = e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i}$ would be included as well, as would $-e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i}$, and so on. However, I have been unable to prove that $S$ contains *every* complex number. Is this true?

Comment: Using $i$ to mean a general complex number is a very bad idea.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $\emptyset\subset \mathbb{C}$ is the smallest I can think of.

Comment: Why would you conclude that necessarily  $\sqrt i\in S$?

Comment: @GitGud Why should it contain the square of $0$?

Comment: I only read "set of complex numbers which contained the squares of every element". I thought he meant every element of $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 5):

The largest such set of complex numbers is simply $\Bbb C$.

This is far from the only such set, though. For other examples, consider $\Bbb R,$ $\Bbb Z,$ $\emptyset,$ $\{0\},$ $\{1\},$ $\{1,-1\},$ $\{1,-1,i\},$ $S^1:=\{z\in\Bbb C: |z|=1\},$ $\Bbb Z[i]:=\{m+ni:m,n\in\Bbb Z\},$ $\overline{B}(0;1):=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|\le 1\},$ $C_n:=\{e^{2\pi ik/n}:k=0,...,n-1\}$ for positive integers $n,$ $\Bbb C^*:=\{z\in\Bbb C: z\neq 0\}.$ There are many others.

---

Your question, unfortunately, is not very well formulated. The answer to the asked question is (as pointed out by copper.hat), not very interesting. If you were looking for the largest *finite* set of complex numbers with this property, then you're out of luck (consider the sets $C_n$ as defined above, noting in particular that $|C_n|=n$).

If you're looking for the largest *strict* subset of $\Bbb C$ with this property, then again, you may once again be out of luck, if by "largest" you mean "contains all other such sets with this property". Let's suppose (by way of contradiction) that there is some $S\subsetneq \Bbb C$ such that $z^2\in S$ for all $z\in S$, with $S\supseteq S'$ whenever $S'\subsetneq \Bbb C$ such that $z^2\in S'$ for all $z\in S'$. But then both $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb C^*$ would be subsets of $S,$ contradicting our assumption that $S$ is a strict subset of $\Bbb C$. On the other hand, there *do* exist strict subsets of $\Bbb C$ with this property that are *maximal* in this sense (that is, they aren't contained in any strictly larger subsets of $\Bbb C$ with this property, except for $\Bbb C$, itself). For an easy example of such a set, consider $\Bbb C^*$, which also provides an example of strict subsets of $\Bbb C$ with this property having the largest possible cardinality.

If you could be a bit more precise about what you're looking for (or perhaps the context in which you're trying to find this set $S$), we might be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You asking to solve the set inequality $S^2 \subset S$. Since $S\subset\mathbb{C}$ implies that $S^2 \subset \mathbb{C}$ (ie, squaring a complex number is still a complex number, looking for the largest such set is not particularly interesting.

One could look for the smallest such set, but this is not particularly interesting either, as the empty set $\emptyset$ satisfies this trivially.

Perhaps you had other conditions in mind?

Answer (score 0):

"However, I have been unable to prove that $S$ contains every complex number. Is this true?"

There are a couple of good answers already, but I just want to address this part directly.

I think you have chosen a particularly difficult way of going about trying to show that the largest such set is $\mathbb{C}$.  In general if you are in a situation where you want to find the largest subset of some set $X$ having a certain property $P$, the very first thing to do is check whether $X$ itself has the property $P$.  If so, then $X$ itself is the desired subset.  
[Checking that $X$ has property $P$ directly is likely to be way easier than deducing by some other argument that the largest subset of $X$ with property $P$ would have to contain every element of $P$.]

So you just need to check that $z^2\in \mathbb{C}$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$.  Well, I'm sure that you know that the square of a complex number is always a complex number, so you're done!